# How to configure brightness for images in React Native

Tags: filter, react-native, brightness

In CSS, the filter property can be used to configure the brightness of an image like so,

```
// using CSS
filter: brightness(50%);
```

How can one achieve the same result in React Native Images?

Answer (score 7):

I figured this out after tinkering with it. To achieve the result below:[image]

JSX:

```
<Image style={styles.universityImage} source={require('./csun.jpg')}>
    <View style={styles.innerFrame}>
        <Text style={styles.universityName}>California State University, Northridge</Text>
        <Text style={styles.universityMotto}>"CSUN Shine"</Text>
    </View>
</Image>
```

StyleSheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
// View tag styling
innerFrame: {
    flex: 1, 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)', 
},
// Image tag styling
universityImage: {
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    borderRadius: 5,
},
universityName: {
    color: '#fff',
    opacity: .9,
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: '500',
    marginVertical: 15,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
},
universityMotto: {
    color: '#fff',
    opacity: .9,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
})
```

Nest a `<View></View>` tag within the `<Image></Image>` and give the view tag `flex: 1` so that it takes up the entire width and height of the parent tag, which is the `<Image></Image>` tag in this case. Then add a `backgroundColor: rbga(0, 0, 0, .5)` to the `<View></View>` tag to give it that opaque appearance. That's it! Hope this helps someone out!

P.S. Within the nested `<View></View>` tag I gave `justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'` so that the text is perfectly in the middle

Comment: This doesn't work for me -- getting an error saying you cannot put child component (i.e. the View) inside of an Image Component in RN.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795666/13789135) answer by @Arvin Flores is good answer but is outdated now, as we cannot nest elements inside an image. But we can do so by using `<ImageBackground>`from react-native which works the same way as image and we can also nest elements inside it. So to make [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795666/13789135) answer working, just replace, `Image` with `BackgroundImage` and also don't  forget to import it from react-native.

Answer (score 0):

React native's CSS support is limited but have a look at this repo: https://github.com/stoffern/gl-react-instagramfilters this might help you get on.